# How to render partial view via ajax with bootstrap multi-select control within the partial

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages, bootstrap-multiselect

Currently returning a partial view via ajax. The partial view returns to the page fine. All elements are shown except one, the bootstrap multi-select drop-down. I suspect that because the partial is being built server side, it has no reference to the bootstrap multi-select library. How can i get this partial to render the bootstrap multi-select dropdown.

Asp.net Core 2.2 app with razor pages. Using the bootstrap multi-select library by David Stutz, see link [multi-select](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#post). I have got this working by not using the multi-select library, however that isn't an option as it leaves the entire UI looking horrible and out of flow.

I know for a fact that the drop-down does work as I have tried rendering this partial on its own without ajax on page-load, and have used the drop-down in many other areas of the app.

This is the element, and this is how I am applying the multi-select tool.

```cs
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItemIds, Model.ItemList, new { @class = "selectpicker", @multiple = "true" })
```

I have also tried adding the following script to the partial (even though this wont work)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're loading your partial view via Ajax, that means your parent view has most likely already loaded. I'm guessing that you have a script section where you do something like;

```js
<!-- Initialize the selectlist plugin: -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').multiselect();
    });
</script>`
```

You can see it will only run once. On the $(document).ready() event.

If you make changes after that, like dynamically injecting your partial view into the parent view, multi-select needs to be triggered again before it will work, because it's not monitoring your HTML.

So when your Ajax call is complete, do `$('#example').multiselect();`

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am loosing all hope here. I have tried as you mention, as the item is dynamically created so is its id etc so doing the following but keep getting the error `.find(...).multiselect is not a function`. Can't seem to figure out which reference I am missing in order  for that to run.

Comment: I have marked your answer @Dennis1679 as it solves the problem. Thanks for pointing me in the direction. However, it didn't quite solve my problem at first and the reason for this was, I was actually not using the library by David Stutz (this is why the `.multiselect()` was throwing an error). I am however using [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/). So what solved it for me was calling `.selectpicker()`. Too many hours on the screen.

Comment: I was facing the same issue..after implementing this now a new issue has come up. My dropdown appears only once and once I click outside the box I am not able to get back the dropdown again. And also the selected box is empty and I am not able to see the values selected.